# How to use python's "input" on Windows Powershell?

Tags: python, windows, powershell

I have a very short python snippet I try to run on a Windows 10 Powershell:

```
 python -c "a=input();print(a)"
```

which does not work. I can try to input values, type the keyboard, press 'Enter' but nothing happens.

It works as expected on the Windows command prompt or under Linux: You enter some text using the keyboard, and after you press "Enter" that same text is printed on the terminal and the program exists.

However on Windows Powershell this code snippet does not seem to work.

Why? How to fix this issue?

Output of  `$PSversiontable`:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.3031
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.3031
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Comment: Works on my machine. What's the output of `$PSversiontable` ?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with stdin and stdout. Can you check where are they directed to?

Comment: Not sure how to check where stdin and stdout is directed to ...

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear about whether this is about Python or PowerShell. I may have guessed wrong, but these work on `Windows PowerShell` and `PowerShell Core`.

```
(py311) PS C:\venv\py311> powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command 'python -c "a=input();print(a)"'
qewr
qewr
(py311) PS C:\venv\py311> pwsh -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command 'python -c "a=input();print(a)"'
asfd
asfd
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to fix this problem: Reboot the computer...